# Copy and paste a fixed column to a master sheet next to each other

Tags: vba

I am trying to copy a fixed column from files in a folder, I am extracting column N only and pasting them onto an active sheet with columns right next to each other. However, I am getting error message, please help me

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory() 
    Dim MyFile As String 
    Dim Filepath As String 
    Dim Wb As Workbook, _ 
        Ws As Worksheet, _ 
        PasteRow As Long 

    Filepath = "\\123.20.0.89\Risk_dept\" 
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 


    MyFile = Dir(Filepath) 
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0 
       If MyFile = "zmaster.xlsm" Then 
         Exit Sub 
        End If 

    PasteCloumn = Ws.Range("A" & Ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column + 1 
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Filepath & MyFile) 
    Worksheets("part 5").Range("N2:N200").Copy 
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").End(xlToRight).Column + 1 
      Applicaiotn.CutCopyMode = False 
  MyFile = Dir 

Loop 

Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Extracts column N from files in folder and pastes them into active sheet.

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
    Dim filePath As String, target As Worksheet, file As String, wb As Workbook, col As Long

    filePath = "\\123.20.0.89\Risk_dept\" 
    Set target = ActiveSheet

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        file = Dir(filePath)

        Do While Len(file) > 0

            If file = "zmaster.xlsm" Then
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filePath & file)

            col = target.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column + 1
            wb.Worksheets("part 5").Range("N2:N200").Copy Destination:=target.Cells(1, col)

        file = Dir

        Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting error messge on this line      Set wb = Workbooks.Open (Filepath & file). The error message was run time error, where my file could not be found, but I am sure that the filepath is correct

Comment: It seems like the `filepath` isn't correct in that case. Go to VBA editor. Open `Immediate window` (CTRL + G). Type in: `?Dir("\\123.20.0.89\Risk_dept\MyFile.xlsx") <> " "` If the `filepath` is valid you should see`True` returned

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for helping, I have tried and it returned TRUE. Am I missing anything because I want to open multiple files from the folder

Comment: If you get `true` then the file does exist. The `loop` should cycle through all files in the folder. It's not clear what the error is. Perhaps replace the inner body of the loop (from `If file..` to `wb.Worksheets...` with `Debug.Print file` to see which file is causing the issue?